RegEx, select EVERYTHING up until a certain sentence?
I'm trying to match all lines of text up until a certain specific sentence in a text file using the VSCode editor, but have failed so far after hours of 'trying to figure regex out' – unfortunately there's on only machine logic to regex no human logic ; )
Something like:
(.?)<specific sentence>


The (.?) should represent ANYTHING – including whitespace and newlines.
I want
to remove
all this text
no matter what
the characters are
up until
THIS SENTENCE <-- I want to keep this sentence (or replace the match with it)

I'm trying to get rid of a long intro text in many documents, so therefore the need of a regex to do the job.
I simply cannot figure out how to also include whitespace and newlines. I've tried adding all combinations of [\n]+, [\r]+, [\n\r]+ (and a million more) I could think of – nothing works.

No, I tried that. But I cannot set /gs as flags in vscode, so that somehow made it not work.

Nowhere, but glad you assumed just something else ; )

You could try this regex, and replace it with nothing.
^[\r\s\S]+?(?=^THIS SENTENCE)

Normally [\s\S] would be sufficient to match any charater including line breaks, but in VSCode it isn't. By adding \r to the set should make it work as intended.
See the test case

And, as always, only AFTER asking the question did I find the answer:
((.|\n)*)
<specific sentence>
<new line character>

